# Filter table that I do a LEFT JOIN with

Tags: postgresql

Here's my query at the moment:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.id
```

Now, suppose there is a table `C` which relates directly to `B`. What I'd like to do is to filter out the records of table `B` based on `C` - how do I do that? I've tried placing the filter in the WHERE section:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.id 
LEFT JOIN C ON B.c_id = C.id 
WHERE C.id > 10
```

The problem is that the preceding queryalso filters out table `A`'s results. How do I achieve the result that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put that filter in join :

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT B.*
   FROM B  
   INNER JOIN C ON B.c_id = C.id AND C.id > 10 
) AS B ON B.a_id = A.id
```

it will not filter out the A's results .

Comment: But it won't filter out the B's results either.

Comment: modified the ans . for that you have to use subquery.

Comment: please vote up and select as a valid ans . it will be very helpful for me .